# openjfx 11 with intellij idea 2018.2

Tags: openjfx

I have existing Java project in which i was using JavaFX. Now i am shifting it to Java 11. I have download openjfx and add its lib directory path to external libraries. Added following in run configuration in VM options:
--module-path /Users//Downloads/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
JavaFX classes are recognised but when i try to build project or run i get module not found error. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your module path in the picture is different from the path you have posted. Make sure you use the correct one

Comment: No, the path in post is just for syntax.